# Mysql backup restoration on higher version too slow

Tags: mysql

Mysql backup taken on  version 5.7.30 is too slow when restoring the same backup on different machine having mysql version 8.0.22-0ubuntu0.20.04.2.

The backup size of database is around 2gb.

Please suggest me how can i optimize the restoration process.

Comment: You can go through this link for full process of upgrade to MYSQL 8 https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-enterprise-backup/8.0/en/restore-upgrade.html

Comment: I am running mysql server on developer machine so no mysql enterprise version available to me